# Hi. I want to give the variables dX and dY a random number, either -2, 0, or 2

Tags: javascript, random

dX = 0;
dY = 0;

right now the Variables are set to 0 but I wan o give them a random number either -2, 0 or 2. I think that math.random() might work, but I don't know how to use it with negative numbers.

Comment: `dX = 4 * Math.random() - 2;`. `Math.random()` gives a number in the range `[0, 1[` (1 not included), so `4 * Math.random()` gives a number in the range `[0, 4[` and `4 * Math.random() - 2` gives you a number in the range `[-2, 2[`

Comment: `0 <= Math.random() < 1`

Comment: `4 * 0 <= 4 * Math.random <= 4 * 1` (multiply by 4)

Comment: `0 <= 4 * Math.random() < 4`

Comment: `0 - 2 <= 4 * Math.random() - 2 < 4 - 2` (subtract 2)

Comment: **`-2 <= 4 * Math.random() - 2 < 2`**

Comment: thanks. I realized that what I was searching doesn't quite work. I can only use -2,0,2 and no other numbers. But these numbers have to be chosen randomly every second.

Comment: Ah! Then you can use [this formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527834/9867451) like so: `dx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 2;`